# Regarding the usage of some 'bad' language

Tags: offensive-language, colloquialisms, historical-change, religion, mass-media

Is there a legitimate or edifying literary purpose for the many forms of blasphemy (forgive spelling) that have appeared in many modern works of literature. Does it really help a story line or plot or character study. There have been many popular movies of the 50's and 60's that have a great plot , interesting characters and hardly any bad language. This shows they could write a great story without it. Why did movies from the 70's on-wards ( and similarly with books) seem to embrace blasphemy and swearing? Does blasphemy and swearing have an important literary use?

Comment: You may find [Writers](http://writers.stackexchange.com) stackexchange more useful for this question.  Suggest you add it there and delete it here.  If you leave it here someone might downvote it or close it and it might not get moved.

Comment: @jwpat7 I think it will be 'off-topic' at writers under the "Questions seeking to interpret or analyze an existing work." rule. This is the only SE site where you can be free and easy with swear words and offensive words (when appropriate).

Comment: But the question probably needs to change to be 'on topic' here so that it's specifically about the usage of blasphemy and swearing rather than inviting opinions about whether it helps a storyline or plot.

Comment: @Frank: the question "Does blasphemy and swearing have an important literary use?" does not regard an existing work - as far as that goes, it's fine at Writers. Course it might be a duplicate.

Comment: @Daniel True, but the question _Why did movies from the 70's on-wards ( and similarly with books) seem to embrace blasphemy and swearing?_ clearly does. It's worth a try at either site though. There is this one http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/922/

Comment: While I can understand your questioning the necessity of widespread use of swearing, it isn't really something that is on topic here. There is a movie and TV SE site; it might be considered there. Please visit the help section to learn what is on topic here.

Comment: You are  confusing various kinds of taboo language each other. Blasphemy and profanity and vulgarity are all different. Blasphemy in particular sounds like something a dangerously wild-eyed religious zealout would rail against, so I advise one to take extreme care in how one presents oneself in this, lest one come off not as a sensitive person but as a medieval quack. In other words, reappropriating a famous saying  of Robert Heinlein’s, [“One man’s blashpemy is the next one’s belly laugh.”](http://atheism.about.com/library/quotes/bl_q_RHeinlein.htm) EG: “Ceiling Cat has a poopy litterbox.”

Comment: Blasphemy: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/blasphemy I'd hate to have to keep track of every sect out there just to avoid this.

Comment: If a person is Christian or Catholic or Muslim or Mormon or of some faith that requires avoiding Blasphemy then they can NOT watch A LOT of modern movies or modern evening T.V. shows. If the majority of Media and T.V. developers are non-religious or irreligious they probably don't care. Great T.V. and movie shows COULD be made without offensive language and thereby reach millions more people; isn't that what storytellers want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that many people are offended by certain words and phrases, but others are desensitized, and others find nothing wrong with them at all.

There are several literary applications. Often, swearing conveys strong emotion. Furthermore, it can reflect the character's personality or opinions. For some characters, it would seem unnatural for them *not* to swear. Sometimes authors and directors go out of their ways to add swearing to show that their work is intended for an audience of a certain age.

Comment: Swearing convey's strong emotions but many older movies have great characters that convey all sorts of emotions without swearing. Also some modern movies with a lot of Blasphemy and swearing have been shown on T.V. like JAWS on the A.M.C. channel with the language edited. The movie Jeepers Creepers was shown on A.M.C without bad language.

Answer (score 1):

Films of the 1950s etc were heavily censored. Writers may have wanted to convey the earthy language used by eg cowboys or gangsters, but they simply weren't allowed.  Films are still censored to the extent they are given ratings as to suitable age groups, though in adult films pretty much anything seems to be allowed now. It's up to the adult whether they want to pay to be offended.

Good writers use blasphemy and swearing to accurately portray the world they are depicting. B & S are commonplace in many areas of life (I'm making no judgement here, it's just how things are). Good writers want to create realistic characters and situations.

Bad writers, I think, use B&S because they think it adds grittiness and will gain them some kind of macho kudos to make up for their bad writing.

Comment: So blasphemy and swearing has a literary use but should it be promoted so much. I have never heard blasphemy in a work or movie about East Indian or Oriental people and/or their religion.